How to put the QED symbol of a proof at the right place inside aligned?
When a proof ends with a aligned* environment, putting \qedhere after the last equation would cause the QED symbol to appear near the last equation not in the end of the line. How it appear in the end of the line?
\begin{proof}
Box completely misplaced: \qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
a&=b \\
a&=b.\qedhere
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}


I find it bad style: the two-line formula should be displayed. Anyway, just end the paragraph, disallow a page break and back up by one line.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
The QED symbol is correctly placed:\qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
a&=b \\
a&=b.
\end{aligned}$\par\nopagebreak\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}
\end{proof}

\end{document}

No space before \qquad.


Why is it necessary to use \mbox{}?

@EmanueleNardi It possibly works without it, but why not make sure that a paragraph starts?

@egreg Thanks, for your trick. I often use this environment.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}[solution]
\mbox{ } $\dots$\$\vdots$\
Therefore, the Riemann sum is \quad $\begin{aligned}[t]
\sum_{i=1}^{4}f(\xi {i} )\Delta x{i}  &= f(3)(1)+f(5)(2)+f(8)(3)+f(9)(1)\
&=  9(1)+25(2)+64(3)+81(1)\
&=  332
\end{aligned}$\par\nopagebreak\vspace{-\baselineskip}\mbox{}
\end{proof}
\end{document}

@somkiat_t The QED symbol is placed correctly. There is an overfull line, though, and TeX warns you about it. I see no reason for not using a display in that case.

@egreg My reason is that I want to use the lines efficiently, so I put the text line in the first line of the equation.

@somkiat_t In that case the equation doesn’t fit, and it’s up to you fixing the issue.

The way you're using a closing aligned environment implies that one would need to calculate the distance from the placement of the regular \qedsymbol to the end of the line (at the right margin). This type of calculation is easiest to do using linegoal.
A macro \qedlineend below uses \linegoal from the linegoal package to place \qedhere at against the right margin.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\newcommand{\qedlineend}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[\linegoal][r]{\qedhere}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
Here is a regular proof.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Box completely misplaced: \qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
  a &= b  \\
  a &= b. \qedlineend
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}

\end{document}

This requires at least two compilations at the first go since the positioning has to be determined first before the remaining line length can be calculated.

Thanks for your answer, very useful for me.

\qedlineend, work for another environment i.e. align*, alignat*, equation*, gather* etc.

This solution works under pdfLaTeX but does not appear to work under LuaLaTeX -- whether or not the unicode-math package is loaded. Is there a fix to make your solution work under LuaLaTeX as well?

@Mico: Precede the loading of linegoal with \let\pdfsavepos\savepos \let\pdflastxpos\lastxpos.

Thanks, this is very helpful!

If I have understood correctly, there's no need to use \qedhere, as the proof environment will automatically position the QED symbol at the end of the statement.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Box completely misplaced: \qquad
\(\begin{aligned}[t]
a&=b \\
a&=b.
\end{aligned}\)
\end{proof}

\end{document}



thanks for your post but I want the qed symbol in the right of last equation.

In that case, I think the only way would be to change the alignment of the aligned environment, am I wrong?

Would switching to \begin{aligned}[b] resolve your issue?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Works fine: (OK)
[
\begin{split}
a&=b\
a&=b.\qedhere
\end{split}
]
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
Works fine: (OK)
\begin{gather*}
\begin{split}
a&=b\
a&=b.\qedhere
\end{split}
\end{gather*}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
Works fine: (OK)
\begin{align*}
a&=b \
a&=b.\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}
Box completely misplaced: \qquad
$\begin{aligned}[t]
a&=b \
a&=b \
a&=b \
a&=b.\qedhere
\end{aligned}$
\end{proof}
\end{document}

If we use \begin{aligned}[b], some texts before it goto the last line of equations too.
